# jqGrid the client side validation modal does not placed correctly when editing last rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid Free version 4.12.0 , enable it's client side validation and make a column editable.

```
{ label: 'amount' , name: 'amount', width: 150, 
  editable: true, editrules :{ number: true, required: true} },
```

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/v5ozLfpm/

When we try to edit first rows ( for example row 2) and enter an string instead of number a modal will appear below the cell which says `(_: Please, enter valid number`)

However when we scroll the grid done and edit row 11, the modal alert displayed far below the grid ...

How can we fix it ?!

Comment: validation not firing in the jsfiddle

Comment: I rechecked and it worked. Did you try to insert a character in amount? This should fire the validation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting the problem! It's the bug in free jqGrid. I fixed it in [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/c554ce4b282f1ee96b0dde06f9787955394b819f). You can verify it on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/v5ozLfpm/1/, which uses the sources from GitHub.

Please don't use old versions of jqGrid and free jqGrid. The version 4.12.0 is old (almost one years old). One should use 4.13.4 or more late version from GitHub. If you would find any bug, I will fix it **in the latest version only**. Only if you can't update the code of free jqGrid now then you can use the fix

```
$.extend($.jgrid, {
    findPos: function (obj) {
        var coordinates = $(obj).offset();
        return [coordinates.left, coordinates.top];
    }
});
```

**only as the temporary solution**. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/v5ozLfpm/2/

**UPDATED:** I posted some more changes in the code of free jqGrid to fix the problem reported in [the issue 278](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/278). The modified demos https://jsfiddle.net/v5ozLfpm/3/ and https://jsfiddle.net/v5ozLfpm/4/ uses the latest free jqGrid code.

Comment: Dear Oleg, the update works in Firefox but not in IE and chrom. Also I see this error in adding a row popup. I have created an issue https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/278. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: I posted the fix to the problem, which you reported. Please see UPDATED part of my answer.